# How to let users access Virtual Machines created in Xenserver

Tags: xenserver

I have created 5 VM in my xenserver, i would like to know if theres any way to have weblogin interface or something which allow our users to connect to a specific VM? or anyway how can i let my users access the virtual machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would your users access a physical server? SAME THING.

Basically concfigure the VM's to have some sort of network login capacitiy - noone wants to go through the hypervisor on a day to day basis to do work in a VM.

Now, depending what you use - windows or unix - those two totally support network access since many many many many years.

Comment: does it mean i have to go for windows remote desktop since im using windows to access the virtual machine?

Comment: Exactly. No need to invovle the host here.

Comment: another question which might be not related to this topic, i have like 5 VM in my LAN network here and i have 1 static public ip which i forwarded the remote desktop port from my router to the machine running xserver. so in order to connect to these VM's through public wan ip can you recommend a solution? because if i enter the public ip in my remote it will try to connect to xenserver...

Comment: THen ask the question. Dont comment. Ask a new question. And it has to be relevant fo professional administration and show basic knowledge - both this additional question misses.